# Bootstrap 3.3.7 but using a lower version of bootstrap.min.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

We're currently using bootstrap 3.3.7's css and it is working fine but the problem is the bootstrap 3.3.7 min js is not compatible with our jquery version (1.5.2). Can we use a different version of bootstrap.min.js instead? or are there any alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: There are possibility of having dependency between these versions.. I would suggest either increase your `jquery` version or reduce your `bootstrap` version compatible with `jquery` version

Comment: The lowest version of jQuery available according to Bootstrap 3.0s dependencies is [1.9.0](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.0.0/bower.json). Even version 2.3.2 requires at least [1.8.0](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/bower.json). So if you cannot upgrade use good old pure javascript: See [Bootstrap Native](https://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/).

Comment: Thanks for answering guys. @vanburen can I still use this datepicker https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ with the bootstrap native JS that you've recommended?